# New to MongoDB. Errors while creating a collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I am not able to create a collection. It gives a sentence in the mongo shell - "Display all 169 possibilities? (y or n)". The code is -

```
db.Lead.insert(
        LeadID: 1,
        MasterAccountID: 100,
        LeadName: 'Sarah',
        LeadEmailID : 'sarah@hmail.com',
        LeadPhoneNumber : '2132155445',
        Details : { 
                StateID: 1,
                TaskID : 1,
                Assigned By : 1001,
                TimeStamp : '10:00:00',
                StatusID : 1
              }             
)
```

Not sure what the issue is. Please help me out with the same.

Regards.

Comment: If it displays that then it probably means you are not actually in the mongodb shell but instead within the Linux shell

Comment: I think I am in the MongoDB shell wherein I enter using the command "C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe". Also, it is in the same shell where I have been successful in creating some other simple collections. This is my first attempt in creating an embedded collection. Can you please try running it at your end & let me know what the error is. It would really be very helpful as I need the results for my Grad Project, deadline in a couple of days.

Comment: Ok well you have problems in your document structure, you need an extra enclosing `{}` around the document, basically you are not inserting a JSON sytnax document into the function signature

Comment: Also it is better to not have spaces: ` Assigned By` if you do you need to enclose them with `""`

Comment: Can you please help me on how to insert a JSON sytnax document into the function signature.

Comment: Dude, judging by your last comment I believe this to be homework, if you dunno how to form a JSON document please Google, we are not here to complete your homework for you...if you cannot complete something then don't lie about it by getting some one else to do it for you.

Comment: Just my initial days. Can I have a chat with you. It would really be very helpful for me to get going.

Comment: Hi Sir.I appreciate all your help.This is not a homework.I have created a Lead Management System in relational db & wanted to get its non-relational counterpart. The non-relational part is just for my learning. I am very new to it & thought if I could get some help from seniors at Stack Overflow. The Mongo Shell doesnt give conclusive errors or warnings, so I found it a little difficult. So, for technologies as these, only forums & people like you can help. But I do understand & respect your call. Thanks anyways. I might have to wait till I get help from someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should generally avoid having spaces in field names.  If you must have them, then they should be quoted.  Also, you are missing some opening and closing braces.  This worked for me:

```
testReplSet:PRIMARY> db.Lead.insert({LeadID: 1, MasterAccountID: 100, LeadName: 'Sarah', LeadEmailID : 'sarah@hmail.com', LeadPhoneNumber : '2132155445', Details : { StateID: 1, TaskID : 1, "Assigned By" : 1001, TimeStamp : '10:00:00', StatusID : 1 }})
testReplSet:PRIMARY> db.Lead.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("517fac61a010d6dfc17bd6ae"),
    "LeadID" : 1,
    "MasterAccountID" : 100,
    "LeadName" : "Sarah",
    "LeadEmailID" : "sarah@hmail.com",
    "LeadPhoneNumber" : "2132155445",
    "Details" : {
        "StateID" : 1,
        "TaskID" : 1,
        "Assigned By" : 1001,
        "TimeStamp" : "10:00:00",
        "StatusID" : 1
    }
}
```

Finally, please note that "Display all 169 possibilities? (y or n)" is message you should only get when attempting to do tab completion.  Even with your incorrect syntax, I did not receive that error.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the part about Display xx possibilities.. in my case the error occurred because the script contained tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You did not put the correct curvy brackets at the beginning and end of the json.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#Schema